# How do I achieve a book-style index with periods in a table with dynamic items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I want to build a menu with trailing periods that end with an arrow, similiar to what you would find in the index of a book (the actual name of this escapes me!). So for example, I want to be able to dynamically generate links (via ASP.NET) and output them in a format like this:

```
Link #1 ............ >>
Link #2 ............ >>
Really Long Link ... >>
```

Keep in mind this:

- I CANNOT use monospaced fonts
- I DO NOT know what the links will be, they are dynamically created by the user

My current approach is this:

```
<tr><td nowrap style='overflow: hidden; width: 400px;'>Link 1</td><td> >> </td></tr>
```

... with the goal of adding "..." to a length GREATER than 400px, and using NOWRAP to keep it to a single line, and overflow:hidden to hide overflowing periods.

The problem is this doesn't work - NOWRAP definitely does not keep it on a single line, and overflow is not hiding anything - is there an approach to achieving this, preferably with tables, using any combination of ASP.NET/CSS/or JS/jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean you cant do monospace font?

Comment: The design requirements are strict - I cannot substitute the desired font with a mono-spaced one

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a background-image of a (repeated) dot and repeat-x that. Then make two divs:

```
<div style="float: left; background-image: url('url'); background-repeat: repeat-x; width: 480px;">
 Link #1
</div>
<div style="float: right">
 &gt;&gt; 
</div>
```

EDIT:

After giving it a more thorough thought, you could indeed set overflow:hidden and append (either hard-coded or via JS) dots until the desired length has been reached. Hard-coding (read: css'ing) the height of the div/td/whatever will make it only have "one line" -- it will however limit you to using one line only as your "Link #n" text...

Answer (score 2):

HTML Nowrap has been deprecated. Css `white-space:nowrap;` is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/syJW2/1/

You can use a list (or table if you prefer) with css:

```css
ul.toc
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.toc li:before
{
    content: ">>";
    float: right;
    background: white;
    position:relative;
}
ul.toc li 
{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will create a list of items (that degrade gracefully) where a `>>` is positioned on the right(with background white so as not to see any dots `...`). 
The `ul` is displayed block to fill the whole area(removing margin/padding to your preferences)

markup like:

```html
<ul class="toc">
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery code:

```js
jQuery("ul.toc li").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text() + "..............................................................................................................................................");
});
```

Or **alternatively** for a pure css/html option: *(that starts to get a bit more complicated)*

http://jsfiddle.net/syJW2/2/

html:

```html
<ul class="toc">
    <li><span class="link">link 1</span><span class="dots">&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><span class="link">link 2</span><span class="dots">&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><span class="link">link 3</span><span class="dots">&nbsp;</div></li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```css
ul.toc
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.toc li:before
{
    content: ">>";
    float: right;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
ul.toc li 
{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.toc li span.link
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

ul.toc li span.dots
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    font-size: 50%;
    display:block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr><td style="position:relative" ><span style="position:absolute; z-index:1px; background-color:White;" >Link 1</span><hr style="border-style:dotted; width:100%" /></td><td width="10px"> >> </td></tr>
</table>
```